# Remove obsolete collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to delete all the collections from my db which are not used for long time. Is there any why i can check when the particular collection was last used?

Comment: Do you have any field in your records, which is updated with every update and insert?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by 'last used'.  If you mean the last time a document was inserted into the collection then you could do this by converting the ObjectId of the last inserted document into a date.  The following query should return the date the last document was inserted:

```
db.<collection_name>.findOne({},{_id:1})._id.getTimestamp()
```

the findOne query will return documents in natural order, therefore if you input no query criteria ('`{}`') then it will return the most recently inserted document.  You can then get the `_id` field and call the `getTimestamp()` function

I'm not sure if there is any way to reliably tell when a collection was last queried.  If you're running your database with profiling enabled then there might be entries in the db.system.profile collection, or in the oplog.